# Set observation value to NA after any lag has an observation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

If any of the lags of my two month return is smaller than -0.7 I want to set every next `closeret` observation to NA.

I tried:

```
x <- x %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(first = { twomonthreturn <= (-0.7) } %>% { . * !duplicated(.) } ) %>%
  mutate(first = ifelse(first==1,datem,NA)) #%>%
  mutate(closeret = ifelse(datem<=sum(first,na.rm = TRUE),closeret,NA))
```

where datem = year(date)*12+month(date)

```
date seriesid price closeret twomonthreturn
2018-07-25 50005 3.100 NA NA
2018-08-14 50005 2.500-0.19354839 NA
2018-09-28 50005 2.350 -0.06000000 -0.24193548
2018-10-27 50005 0.800 -0.65957447 -0.68000000 
2018-11-27 50005 0.500 -0.37500000 -0.7872340
2018-12-31 50005 0.300 -0.40000000 -0.62500000
2019-01-26 50005 0.360 0.20000000 -0.28000000
2019-02-23 50005 0.300 -0.16666667 0.00000000
2017-01-21 50006 7.000 NA NA
2017-03-28 50006 9.750 NA NA
2017-04-14 50006 8.875 -0.08974359 NA
2017-05-20 50006 9.000 0.01408451 -0.07692308
2017-06-22 50006 9.000 0.00000000 0.01408451
```

I am looking to find the solution for every group, my solution works for group one but of course if there is no first because it is NA, this solution does not work.

```
date seriesid price closeret twomonthreturn
2018-07-25 50005 3.100 NA NA
2018-08-14 50005 2.500-0.19354839 NA
2018-09-28 50005 2.350 -0.06000000 -0.24193548
2018-10-27 50005 0.800 -0.65957447 -0.68000000 
2018-11-27 50005 0.500 -0.37500000 -0.7872340
2018-12-31 50005 0.300 NA -0.62500000
2019-01-26 50005 0.360 NA -0.28000000
2019-02-23 50005 0.300 NA 0.00000000
2017-01-21 50006 7.000 NA NA
2017-03-28 50006 9.750 NA NA
2017-04-14 50006 8.875 -0.08974359 NA
2017-05-20 50006 9.000 0.01408451 -0.07692308
2017-06-22 50006 9.000 0.00000000 0.01408451
```

Comment: please always post `dput(mydata)` instead of the print version of your `data`. 
This makes it easier to work with your data.

Comment: Thanks Cettt, how do i do it if my df is a data table? i selected rows 6-13 and 84-88

Comment: Can you also add your expected output? It would be easier to understood what you're trying to do

Comment: @Bart `dput(mydata[c(6:13, 84:88), ]`

Comment: @DS_UNI, uploaded it , dput(x[c(6:13,84:88),c(1,4,6,9,10)], file = "r.rds") does not give me a file containing what i need.

Comment: just run `dput(x[c(6:13,84:88),c(1,4,6,9,10)])` without `file = "r.rds"`, then copy-paste the output

Comment: Second table is the desired output?

Comment: Yes @ubutun!    it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one will work:

### Solution

Feed `replace` with `cumsum(lag(replace_na(twomonthreturn, Inf), , Inf) <= -.7) > 0` which serve as an indices for all values in a group *after* `- 0.7` in `twomonthreturn`, so it replace all such values in `closered` with `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  arrange(seriesid, date) %>%
  group_by(seriesid) %>%
  mutate(
    closeret = replace(
      closeret,
      cumsum(lag(replace_na(twomonthreturn, Inf), , Inf) <= -.7) > 0,
      NA_real_
      )
    ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   date       seriesid price closeret twomonthreturn
   <date>        <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 2018-07-25    50005  3.1   NA             NA     
 2 2018-08-14    50005  2.5   -0.194         NA     
 3 2018-09-28    50005  2.35  -0.06          -0.242 
 4 2018-10-27    50005  0.8   -0.660         -0.68  
 5 2018-11-27    50005  0.5   -0.375         -0.787 
 6 2018-12-31    50005  0.3   NA             -0.625 
 7 2019-01-26    50005  0.36  NA             -0.28  
 8 2019-02-23    50005  0.3   NA              0     
 9 2017-01-21    50006  7     NA             NA     
10 2017-03-28    50006  9.75  NA             NA     
11 2017-04-14    50006  8.88  -0.0897        NA     
12 2017-05-20    50006  9      0.0141        -0.0769
13 2017-06-22    50006  9      0              0.0141
```

### Data

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "date seriesid price closeret twomonthreturn
2018-07-25 50005 3.100 NA NA
2018-08-14 50005 2.500 -0.19354839 NA
2018-09-28 50005 2.350 -0.06000000 -0.24193548
2018-10-27 50005 0.800 -0.65957447 -0.68000000 
2018-11-27 50005 0.500 -0.37500000 -0.7872340
2018-12-31 50005 0.300 -0.40000000 -0.62500000
2019-01-26 50005 0.360 0.20000000 -0.28000000
2019-02-23 50005 0.300 -0.16666667 0.00000000
2017-01-21 50006 7.000 NA NA
2017-03-28 50006 9.750 NA NA
2017-04-14 50006 8.875 -0.08974359 NA
2017-05-20 50006 9.000 0.01408451 -0.07692308
2017-06-22 50006 9.000 0.00000000 0.01408451",
  colClasses = c("Date", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"),
  header     = TRUE
)
```